# Firebase AuthData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble migrating from Firebase to Google Firebase to my iOS Swift.
In Firebase, I use `NSUD.standarUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") && currentUser.authData != nil` to check whether the current user has local and remote uid, but i couldn't find the similar term in Google Firebase.
Could you help me with this? I just want to check both of key is not equal to nil.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Firebase you can simply just check if a user exists (and is signed in) by `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser`